# How to get an Eclipse-like class outline in VS 2008/C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, eclipse, user-interface

I've just recently started using VS2008 for a new tools project, and have been spending a lot of time in Eclipse/Java. The one thing I am missing is the thing I could have sworn was in VS2005 the last time I worked with it - the class outline.

I'm speaking of the basic outline in Eclipse, where you can see the class members, methods, etc and click on them to navigate to them.

The only thing that sounds like it might be it (but is not) is the Class View.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably the closest addin that you'll find that has it:

- [Source Code Outliner Power Toy](http://sourcecodeoutliner.codeplex.com/)

(The window on the left is what it adds to Visual Studio)

[alt text http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=SourceCodeOutliner&DownloadId=3493](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=SourceCodeOutliner&DownloadId=3493)

- "You can dock the Source Code Outliner anywhere, like to the left side of the Visual Studio window next to the Code Editor window."
- "Click a method or variable name in Source Outliner and the code associated with what you clicked displays near the top of the Code Editor window."

Comment: That appears to be the one. Didn't this used to be built in?

Comment: The class view may have had it at one point, not sure. You need to close the window when you're typing or it'll keep refreshing

Comment: Might be worth to mention that this tool doesn't work for .ashx files. Probably for the same reasons VS itself doesn't support code folding for those files.

Answer (score 3):

JetBrains Reshaper.

Comment: I am using Resharper, but I don't see any outliner in it.

Comment: ReSharper > Windows > File Structure View

Answer (score 3):

This is what I had to do:

Open the Object Browser (View->Object Browser). It will open as a tab.

Right click the tab and select the "dockable" option. Then it will open as a window floating around.

I have 2 monitors, so in one of them I have visual studio, and in the other I put the Object Browser window. If you click something in the Object Browser, it will take you to where it is defined in the visual studio editor.

Not the same as the Eclipse outline (I miss it too), but this is the closest to it I'have found without adding pluggins.

Answer (score 2):

Try this menu option:

> `View > Class View`

The default keyboard shortcut is

> `Control + Shift + C`

Comment: It even says right in the question that is not what I am looking for.