# Visual Studio 2005 - Missing feature 'Code outline' (eclipse) or 'Defs' (SlickEdit)

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, slickedit

I mostly use SlickEdit and eclipse while working on embedded systems. Once in a while I need to use Visual Studio, and I terribly miss this feature that is known by different names in different editors. Basically you get a small window of 'outline style' code summary on the side (showing just the function names and optionally the static and globals at the top). You click an item on this little window and your cursor in the main editor window magically jumps to that item location. Here is how it looks like in SlickEdit:

http://sites.google.com/site/fractalspace/tmp1

Anyone knows what I am talking about ?

Any 'pointers' will be much appreciated :)
Thanks.

Comment: I know what you're talking about - but unfortunately the one I'm aware of is for VS2008 see here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/BEA9ED59-8857-4032-9666-9AF1C1A33969

Comment: This post has a couple options that may suit your fancy.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794971/how-to-get-an-eclipse-like-class-outline-in-vs-2008-c)

Comment: Thanks Murph. This one does have a VS2005 version as well and seem to do what I am looking for. Unfortunately I couldn't make it work. In one PC, its window is always greyed out. In another PC, it crashed the VS and failed to install. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [DPack](http://www.usysware.com/dpack/) addin

and more specifically at the [Code Browser](http://www.usysware.com/dpack/CodeBrowser.aspx) feature

Comment: Thanks Konstantinos. This one does the job as desired, but it comes with one very annoying 'feature': When in use, it wants to stay on top of all other windows (and grabs focus and control) and cannot be docked. Would have been much useful if could sit quietly on the side doing the same thing. Or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: After a minor (but not so obvious) setting, the tool can work as expected: In a "tool window" (as opposed to the default "Dialog window"). This tool is my new friend now.